# What is replacement of below code with ga('send', 'pageview') method

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

What is replacement of below code with `ga('send', 'pageview')` method?

```
var _gaq = _gaq || []; // variable declare
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']); // set account
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mydomail.com']); // set domain
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]); // allow linker
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); // set pageview
```

Comment: Please provide some code that you tried to solve this that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

---

Please proceed with precaution here. Google updated the libraries to `gtag` and you can learn more from [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/topic/1008079?visit_id=1-636540763190048747-3321846229&rd=1).

Best practice is to use a tag management system like Google Tag Manager, which will reduce all the efforts you are putting right now.

Comment: Thanks Tushar, so below code would works?
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', {allowLinker: true});
    ga('require', 'linker');
    ga('linker:autoLink', ['source.com', 'destination.com']);

Answer (score 0):

It would be of the form:

`_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/xyz/abc.html']);`